# Kafka bindings without @EnableBinding annotations in Spring

Tags: spring, binding, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using spring cloud to connect to my Kafka broker.  It works fine.  Now I want to create my binding by code instead of annotation.
Is there a convenient way to do it?

Comment: In the listener part you can read directly from the kafka broker by using kafka consumer, also kafka producer at the source end. With out using annotations. Is that u need ?.

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate why do you want to do the binding programmatically instead of using `@EnableBinding`.

While Spring Cloud Stream simplifies exactly that, if you prefer to use your own way of connecting (for any other specific reason), then you might want to check the Spring Integration adapters to do the binding. But, in this case, you are on your own by setting up the lifecycle and all other goodies that Spring Cloud Stream provides.

If you still want to use Spring Cloud Stream but don't want to use the annotation, then check [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/annotation/EnableBinding.java#L47) to see all the configuration that Spring Cloud Stream does when you annotate and apply your use case.

Comment: I think I've to for the moment.  But no documentation... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Please follow https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/954. We plan to add this feature to 1.3.0.RC1.

Comment: That will be awesome.